# Passar conteúdo de template para view Django

Tags: django

Bom eu sei que é possível pegar conteúdo de uma view e passar para um template.

Porém a dúvida seria como pegar o "value" de um input e passar para uma view, um exemplo do uso seria.

Pegar o value de um input html:

```
<input type="text" name="celular" id="id_celular" value= "xx-xxx" class="form-control">
```

E passar este value para uma Query na view exemplo:

```
teste = x.objects.all().filter(celular= "COLOCAR O VALUE AQUI")
```

Se for necessário posto o código completo.

Comment: Basta fazer uma requisição HTTP enviando o valor. O `<input>` está em um formulário? Se sim, ao submeter o formulário a requisição é feita e o valor enviado para a rota que você definiu para a *view*.

Comment: Anderson o  <input> está em um formulário porém inicialmente o input não tem nenhum valor. so após o usuário digitar algo ele teria que pegar o value, e completar o resto dos inputs do formulario com base neste value.

Comment: Então pesquise sobre requisições AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

A maneira recomendada pra fazer isso é usando o [formulários](https://docs.djangoproject.com/pt-br/2.2/topics/forms/) do Django, ficaria algo mais ou menos assim.

```py
# forms.py
from django import forms

class NameForm(forms.Form):
    celular = forms.IntegerField(label='Número de telefone', max_length=11)
```

```py
# views.py
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Celular
from .forms import NameForm

def get_name(request):
    # se for uma requisição POST
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # cria um formulario NameForm com os campos que foram digitados
        form = NameForm(request.POST)
        # checa se é um formulário válido:
        if form.is_valid():
            # pega o número digitado
            number = form.cleaned_data['celular']
            teste = x.objects.all().filter(celular=number)
            # ...

    # se a validação der erro vai aqui
    else:
        form = NameForm()

    return render(request, 'name.html', {'form': form})
```

Agora é só adaptar pra seu caso, der uma olhada no link que passei lá tem uns exemplos mais completos, uma [outra maneira seria associa um modelo com um form](https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/pt/django_forms/)

Comment: Tentei realizar desta forma, porém é necessário um botão para validar o formulario, gostaria que ele olhasse sempre que o usuario digitasse algo na input e ficasse fazendo a busca.

Comment: Ah nesse caso eu só sei fazer usando JavaScript(AJAX), quando se trata de um nível de interatividade como essa só com JS mesmo

Comment: Como faria usando ajax e JS?

Answer (score 0):

Usando AJAX você consegue facilmente, mas para isso vamos usar uma ferramenta especial, e configurar da forma correta.

Primeiro você precisa instalar o [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios). Ele é um client http que pode ser adicionado ao seu html pela tag script como você pode ver na documentação.

O que vamos fazer?

1. Pegar o momento em que o valor é alterado.
2. Enviar para o django por meio do axios.

Você pode fazer isso tanto com funções diretas no elemento, ou com event listener. Dentro dessa função você deve pegar o valor do input, usando o evento onInput(seja em funções diretas, ou com listener). Dentro dessa função você fará a chamada para a view.

```
let data = 'valor do input'      
axios.post('url-da-view', data, config)
.then((res)=>{
   //aplique as mudanças no DOM aqui
})
.catch((erros)=>{
  //Pegue os erros aqui.
})
```

Beleza, parece que terminamos certo? NOP. Tá vendo aquela variável config, na chamada do axios? Ali temos que enviar um cookie para o django, para que o back-end se proteja de ataques CSRF. Segundo a [documentação](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/csrf/) do Django devemos copiar a seguinte função para pegar o cookie:

```
function getCookie(name) {
let cookieValue = null;
if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
    const cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
        const cookie = cookies[i].trim();
        // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
        if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
            cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
            break;
        }
    }
}
return cookieValue;}

const csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
```

Para enviarmos esse cookie no axios usamos aquela variável config.

```
const config = {
    // O nome do header é o Django que dá, por padrão. Mas você pode mudar nas configurações.
    headers: {
        ''X-CSRFToken': csrftoken,
    }
}
```

Logo após ajustar as configurações, você envia sua requisição axios.